# Wordpress Cache delete on plugin uninstall

Tags: plugins, php, themes, mysql, cache

I am developing a custom plugin in which I am storing some data in Cache using cacheKey.
I was wondering in this case if I should write someting in the uninstall.php file, more specific, if there is any command to clear cache or something like that, even though the data is not stored locally.

Thank you!

Code:

```
function showPageHits($attributes)
{
  /** @var \WP_Query $wp_query */
  global $wp_query;
  $page = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
  if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user()->ID;
    $meta = get_user_meta($user, 'pagehits', true) ?: [
      'page' => [
        $page => 0,
      ],
    ];
    $meta['pages'][$page]++;
    update_user_meta($user, 'pagehits', $meta);
  } else {
    $address = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] ?? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $cacheKey = 'pagehits_' . $address;
    $meta = get_transient($cacheKey) ?: [
      'page' => [
        $page => 0,
      ],
    ];
    $meta['pages'][$page]++;
    set_transient($cacheKey, $meta);
  }
  echo sprintf(_n('You have visited this page: %d time', 'You have visited this page: %s times', $meta['pages'][$page]), $meta['pages'][$page]);
}
```

Comment: you can also set expiration times on transients and they'll be automatically cleaned up

Answer (score 0):

It's always good to clear your own stuff on uninstallation. I see you're using `set_transient`. There also is a `delete_transient` function ([docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/delete_transient/)). I think that's the only thing you need to clean things up.